# From a class, call a function from an activity

Tags: java, android

I have made a class(Paperclip), that makes a custom dialogbox appear on screen. On my activity   I create an instance of Paperclip and make the dialogbox show over the activity. What I want is that when a certain button is pressed, some code on the activity is executed. I want this code to be executed from the activity, because I want a dialog box that I can reuse on lots of different activities within the project.

I was thinking of making a variable in the class, and attach a listener to it on the activity. Is this a good way, or is there an easier solution?

```
public class Paperclip {
    int i = 0;
    Dialog myDialog;
    TextView t;
    int mid;
    Context context2;

    public Paperclip(Context context) {
        super();
        context2 = context;
    }

    public void Showit(final String[] Messages) {
        final int lengte = Messages.length;

        myDialog = new Dialog(context2, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.messagebox);
        t = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
        if (lengte != 0) {
            if (i < lengte) {
                t.setText(Messages[i]);
                i++;
            }
            Button iets = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.mbja);
            iets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i < lengte) {
                        t.setText(Messages[i]);
                        i++;
                    } else{
                        t.setText("Ik hoop dat deze informatie nuttig was. Klik op Ja om alles opnieuw te horen.");
                        i = 0;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        Button iets2 = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        iets2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button iets3 = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        iets2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO: execute code from activity here.
            }
        });

        myDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add code snippets

Comment: Unless you want to make the dialog a component (reusable in other projects) I would just pass to it a reference to the activity instance and call the method directly.

Comment: you should read a bit about [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set an `OnClickListener` on a `Button` and call your method inside the `onClick()` event.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Button myButton;
    String[] mMessages = new String[]{"Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Paperclip p = new Paperclip(MyActivity.this);
                p.showit(mMessages);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: Corrected typos & updated code
Edit #2: Updated code based on updated question and code snippet

Comment: The button is in a dialogbox, inside a class. So this will not work for me I guess.

Comment: Edit: Misunderstood the comment.Anyways, it would be best to read about (dialogs)[http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html] and DialogFargment, as suggested by thepoosh.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of the dialogbox button in your activity and add a listener event to it and post your code inside this listener

Answer (score 0):

you can Try using broadcast besides listener, implement the broadcast in the activity and send it from your class
here's good [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)